# JavaFX Focused Button UnderLine

Tags: java, javafx

I made `Button`, and I Shaped it with `Rectangle` and changed background color.

---

**Source Code:**
MainApplication.java:

```
AnchorPane anchor  = new AnchorPane();
    anchor.maxWidth(325);
    Button[] buttons = new Button[3];
    String[] buttonName = new String[]{"Player","World","Log"};
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i ++){
        Button button = new Button();
        button.setText(buttonName[i]);
        button.setShape(new Rectangle(100, 25));
        button.setMaxWidth(100);
        button.setMinWidth(100);
        button.setMaxHeight(25);
        button.setMinHeight(25);
        button.setId("tabButton");
        StackPane stack = new StackPane();
        stack.setMaxWidth(100);
        stack.setMaxHeight(25);
        stack.setMinWidth(100);
        stack.setMinHeight(25);
        RippingCircle circle = new RippingCircle();//just a rippleAnimation
        circle.setToSize(Math.sqrt(100 * 100 + 25 * 25));
        circle.setFromSize(0.0);
        circle.setFill(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
        Rectangle clip = new Rectangle(-50, -12.5, 100, 25);
        circle.setClip(clip);
        stack.getChildren().addAll(button, circle);
        stack.setLayoutX(100 * i);
        stack.setLayoutY(0);
        button.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent){
                StackPane.setMargin(circle, new Insets((mouseEvent.getY() - 12.5) * 2, 0, 0, (mouseEvent.getX() - 50) * 2));
                clip.setX(-mouseEvent.getX());
                clip.setY(-mouseEvent.getY());
                circle.play();
            }
        });
        button.setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent){
                circle.stop();
            }
        });
        anchor.getChildren().add(stack);
        buttons[i] = button;
    }
```

MainApplication.css:

```
#tabButton {
-fx-background-color: #03A9F4;
-fx-text-fill: rgba(150,255,255,255);
-fx-font: 12 Arial;
-fx-focus-color: #FFEB3B;
-fx-faint-focus-color: #FFEB3B;
-fx-accent: #FFEB3B;
}
#tabButton:hover {
    -fx-background-color: #039BE5;
    -fx-text-fill: rgba(150,255,255,255);
    -fx-font: 12 Arial;
    -fx-focus-color: #FFEB3B;
    -fx-faint-focus-color: #FFEB3B;
    -fx-accent: #FFEB3B;
}
#tabButton:focused {
    -fx-background-color: #03A9F4;
    -fx-text-fill: rgba(255,255,255,255);
    -fx-font: 12 Arial;
    -fx-focus-color: black;
    -fx-faint-focus-color: black;
}
```

---

when it focused, an underline appears under the `Player` button:

[image]

like this.
What's this underline, and how can I change it's color?

Comment: BTW: You don't have to repeat the properties set in the `#tabButton` rule unless you want to override the value. E.g. everything but `-fx-background-color: #039BE5;` is unnecessary in your second rule. Also your GUI would probably benefit from modifying the look of a button that is hovered and focused, i.e. specifying a rule for `#tabButton:hover:focused`. Furthermore if multiple Nodes should be styled the same you usually use a style class not the same id for every node.

Answer (score 2):

I think it belongs to the focus, if you want to hide it :

```
-fx-background-insets:0;
```

or change color :

```
-fx-focus-color: red;
-fx-faint-focus-color: red;
```

Good luck !

Comment: in MainApplication.css, I already changed color but the underline is still white.